# how to use find function and if-statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm having issues with if-statement not working as I hope

```
const currentlyActive = response.data.find(
    e =>
      e.teamMemberEmail === firebase.auth().currentUser.email && e.isActive,
);
```

**NOTE** if results are false, then I am getting the follow from `currentlyActive: undefined`

```
// My issue
 
if (currentlyActive._id !== 'undefined' || null) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

console.log gives me an error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'activeSearch._id')

However if there is a result from `currentlyActive` then my console.log shows the hello message.

How do I fix the error message:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'activeSearch._id')

when there are no result from `currentlyActive`?

Comment: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) returns *undefined* if no match is found.

Comment: What do you expect `if (currentlyActive._id !== 'undefined' || null)` to do, exactly? Because it's almost certainly not what it will actually do.

Comment: to keep it basic. If its undefined or null just console.log('no data') and if there is different value then console.log('some data here')

Answer (score 2):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
  if (currentlyActive?._id) {
      console.log('hello')
  }
```